# What is n= n ^1U<<i?

Tags: c++, c, loops, iteration, bit-manipulation

The problem I am facing here is to understand the change in the value of `n` in each iteration of the loop.
If you explain it by taking 2-3 iteration that will be awesome.
correction -return value should be of 32 bit ....which is altering all bits 0->1 ans 1->0 .

```
long fun(long n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        n = n ^ 1U << i;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: `n` is a variable (argument) of type `long`

Comment: Do you know about [operator precendence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and what [bitwise xor and bitshift](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) do? Then it should be easy to figure out what it does.

Comment: What is the return type of `fun`? Is the size of `long` known?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`i` is counting.
`1U << i` is a single unsigned bit (LSB), which gets shifted in each turn by `i` to the left, i.e. it scans the bit positions, 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000 (read as binary please).
`n = n ^ 1U << i` sets `n` to a XOR of `n` and the shifted bit. I.e. it XORs `n` bit by bit completely.
The result is a completely inverted `n`.

Lets look at 4 iterations on the example 13, 1101 in binary.

```
1101 ^ 0001 is 1100
1100 ^ 0010 is 1110
1110 ^ 0100 is 1010
1010 ^ 1000 is 0010

0010 is 1101 ^ 1111
```

As Eric Postpischil mentions:

> The parameter `n` to the function is a `long`, but the code iterates `i` through only 32 bits. It flips the low 32 bits in `n`, leaving high bits, if any, unaltered.
> If `long` is 32 bits, then `n = n ^ 1U << i` is implementation-defined in some cases since the `^` of a `long` with an `unsigned int` will result in an `unsigned long`, and, if the resulting value cannot be represented in a `long`, the result is implementation-defined.

If we assume suitable input of `n`, e.g. being representable in the 32-bit wide type, or that the flipping of only lower bits is intentional, then that is not a problem.
Note with this and with Eric's comment, that a `long` is implicitly signed, which implies that the quasi MSB is not fully available for value representation (whether 2-complement or 1-complement or sign representation), because half of the range is used for negative values. Toggling it via a XOR then has potentially weird effects.

Answer (score 1):

It will flip the lower 32 bits in `n`. That total effect would be the same as just doing `n ^= 0xFFFF`.

In your code, `n` is `long`. If you're on a 32-bit compiler, then it'll have 32 bits, but it could be longer on other compilers.

If you unroll the loop, you get something like this:

```
n = n ^ 1U << 0;
n = n ^ 1U << 1;
n = n ^ 1U << 2;
...
```

Since `<<` has higher precedence than `^`, that will resolve to this:

```
n = n ^ 1;
n = n ^ 2;
n = n ^ 4;
...
```

The end effect is that it flips 32-bits of `n`, one bit at a time.

Comment: The parameter `n` to the function is a `long`, but the code iterates `i` through only 32 bits. It flips the low 32 bits in `n`, leaving high bits, if any, unaltered.

Comment: If `long` is 32 bits, then `n = n ^ 1U << i` is implementation-defined in some cases since the `^` of a `long` with an `unsigned int` will result in an `unsigned long`, and, if the resulting value cannot be represented in a `long`, the result is implementation-defined.